# Could not find part of path for pdf generate

Tags: pdf-generation, itext

I want to generate pdf report.But error in path not found. This code work well in localhost. but not work in live server. On live server all folders are created and set all permission also.

```
 Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
    var PdfFileName = "/Resources/StatementReport/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy_hh_mm_ss_tt") + ".pdf";
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Server.MapPath(PdfFileName), FileMode.Create));
```

Comment: Have you debugged what `Server.MapPath(PdfFileName)` is on the live server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved.
 Error in convert datetime.
I replace fileName Postfix: dd/MM/yyyy_hh_mm_ss_tt TO dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_ss_tt